# Lodash - can you continue chaining after variable declaration?

Tags: javascript, lodash, chaining

This bit of code:

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3],
    bar = _.chain(foo)
            .map(number => number * 2);


console.log(bar.value());

bar.tap(numbers =>  {
  numbers.push(10000);
});

console.log(bar.value());
```

The `10000` won't be added to the `bar.value()`.  However if I move the tap to chain during the actual variable chain, it works fine.  I'm certain this has something to do with the context of where `tap` is called, but can anyone explain?  Seems like it would be nice to init a chain and then modify it later.  Thanks!

Bin for demonstration: http://jsbin.com/kidomeqalo/edit?html,js,console

JS Bin on jsbin.com

Comment: You surely meant `.tap(numbers => { …`?

Comment: Looks like `tap` is lazy, like most other methods, and won't get called until you get the `.value()` out of the result (and of course, you should not use it for side effects).

Comment: @Bergi yes, thanks, that's a typo

Comment: @Bergi yeah, that's a typo, fixed it now.  So I'm not sure I follow, shouldn't `bar` be something that could be continued chaining?  IE I could continue the chain if I just add the `.tap` after the `.map`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: But you *can* continue to chain onto `bar`. `tap` just doesn't do anything in your example. If you used `console.log(bar.tap(…).value())` you'd get your result. Notice that calling `bar.tap(…);` doesn't "add" anything to the chain, it just creates a new value (which you then throw away, and start back at `bar` again).

Comment: And there's the light bulb moment :)  I assumed since tap should modify the values of the array being worked on that pushing something on to the tap interceptor would modify the same array in memory, which is, not the case apparently. Thanks for the response!  If you want to submit an answer I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a `bar.tap();` doesn't change anything. You will need to actually include it in the chain:

```
bar = bar.tap(numbers =>  {
  numbers.push(10000);
});
console.log(bar.value());
```

or

```
console.log(bar.tap(numbers =>  {
  numbers.push(10000);
}).value());
```

On top of that, you should not use `tap` for executing side effects. Rather use `bar.concat(10000).value()` or something like that, which makes clear that it creates a new result in a functional way instead of mutating anything - which becomes especially confusing as sequences are evaluated lazily.